# Anki won't start on Ubuntu 20.04 because of Qt error

Tags: ubuntu, qt

I am tying to run Anki on Ubuntu 20.04 by following the instructions on their webpage. However, trying to start it from either the command line or apps menu does not work. The error is the following:

```
Qt info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. 
Qt fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

Running `sudo make install` or installing xcb doesn't fix the issue. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why didn't you install a version already available in Ubuntu?

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anki

Comment: The official page does not mention anything about it. It has instructions for a tar install.

Comment: @AnSOUser  Normally you install packages available in your distro. Under rare special circumstances you can compile applications but generally it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue on Linux Mint 18.2 by

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0
```